# How to simultaneously access the same MySQL database in the main column and sidebar of Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wordpress

I've wrote some basic custom PHP code for my Wordpress site. The code basically access a MySQL database (a different database from the wordpress database) and displays the information. In addition to running it on the main page, I also need it to run on the sidebar. The code functions perfectly in the main page *or* it functions perfectly in the sidebar, but when I put the code in both, I get the following error in the sidebar:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/kimusubi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(44) : eval()'d code on line 5**

I thought it was an issue of accessing the same table and database at the same time, but I'm using include_once and closing my connection as soon as I'm done with it, so I'm not sure what the problem is. This is the code that I'm using for the sidebar and the main column page:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_config.php'; //Include database configuration file
$current_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login; //Get current WP logged in user
try { //Access accounts table and pull user info into associative array
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accnt = :accnt");
    $STH->bindParam(':accnt', $current_user);
    $STH->execute();
    $Result = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $DBH = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Select Accounts Table Error: " .$e->getMessage(). "</br>"; //Display Error (if any)
}

$available = min($Result['week_two'],$Result['week_one'],$Result['current']);

echo "Account: " .$Result['accnt']. "</br>";
echo "Name: " .$Result['first']. " " .$Result['last']. "</br>";
echo "Address: " .$Result['address']. ", " .$Result['city']. ", " .$Result['state']. ", " .$Result['zip']. "</br>";
echo "Phone: " .$Result['phone']. "</br>";
echo "Current Balance: $" .$Result['current']. "</br>";
echo "Available Balance: $" .$available. "</br>";
?>
```

And this is what's in my db_config.php file:

```
<?php
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Select DB Error: " .$e->getMessage(). "</br>";
}

?>
```

Exec-PHP is the only plugin I'm using in order to execute PHP directly from Wordpress. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What it looks like is the db connection object is destroyed before using it in the code. And include_once causes it to not be initialize again.

Comment: Doesn't include_once check to see if its initialized already, and if not, include it again? Also, if I use 'include' instead of 'include_once', will that maintain multiple active connections? I'm trying to be very careful about how many active connections I have because I'm limited in the number of simultaneous connections on my server.

Comment: No, `include_once` is the right thing to use in general, but if the result of the include goes out of scope, `_once` becomes hilariously ineffective.  Instead of returning the PDO object directly from the include, have the include define a *function* that returns the object if it's been created already, otherwise building a new one.  This is called the Singleton pattern, and is very unpopular around these parts... but I won't tell anyone if you won't!